# Aluminium plate being used in an AUV

Tags: aluminum

I am currently using a AI-6061-T6 plate measuring 750mmx370mmx6mm as a rack between two frames at about 3/4 meter above ground. The load on the plate would be about 8-12kg. How much load will be able to take before bending? And how would the plate react underwater at a depth of 3-4m? Please help.

Comment: A sketch or picture of your setup would help clarify what you're talking about. Also, you should know that the plate is going to 'bend' no matter how small of a force is applied to it. In engineering design there are two typical questions: *how much force will make it bend by a specific amount?* and *how much force/stress will make it break?*

Comment: For a better definition of the problem please also consider drafting or describing the joint of plate to the frames, and include whether this 12 kg is the only load. Then answer posters can include specific info. Otherwise we can reply taking into account several assumptions and we would much probably miss the question.